# Solving Allocation Problem using greedy heuristic

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, greedy

I am trying to solve this problem: https://open.kattis.com/problems/workstations

> Penelope is part of the admin team of the newly built supercomputer.
>   Her job is to assign workstations to the researchers who come here to
>   run their computations at the supercomputer. Penelope is very lazy and
>   hates unlocking machines for the arriving researchers. She can unlock
>   the machines remotely from her desk, but does not feel that this
>   menial task matches her qualifications. Should she decide to ignore
>   the security guidelines she could simply ask the researchers not to
>   lock their workstations when they leave, and then assign new
>   researchers to workstations that are not used any more but that are
>   still unlocked. That way, she only needs to unlock each workstation
>   for the first researcher using it, which would be a huge improvement
>   for Penelope.
>
> Unfortunately, unused workstations lock themselves automatically if
>   they are unused for more than  minutes. After a workstation has
>   locked itself, Penelope has to unlock it again for the next researcher
>   using it. Given the exact schedule of arriving and leaving
>   researchers, can you tell Penelope how many unlockings she may save by
>   asking the researchers not to lock their workstations when they leave
>   and assigning arriving researchers to workstations in an optimal way?
>   You may assume that there are always enough workstations available.

(Please see the link, it has examples and is better formatted).

My approach is a greedy algorithm.

I first sort by end times.

I iteratively record the end time for a given work time. For new work time, I find the closest workstation whose end time is smaller than the start time of this new work time. If there is none, it is not possible to exploit unlocking.

The code:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.max

private fun readLn() = readLine()!! // string line
private fun readInt() = readLn().toInt() // single int
private fun readLong() = readLn().toLong() // single int

private fun readStrings() = readLn().split(" ") // list of strings
private fun readInts() = readStrings().map { it.toInt() } // list of ints
private fun readLongs() = readStrings().map { it.toLong() } // list of longs



fun greedy(times: List<Pair<Long, Long>>, m: Long): Long {
    val sortedTimes = times.sortedBy { it.second }
    val counter = mutableMapOf<Long, Long>()
    val treeSet = TreeSet<Long>()
    var count: Long = 0
    for (i in 0 until sortedTimes.size) {
        val currentStart = sortedTimes[i].first
        val prev = treeSet.lower(currentStart + 1)
        if (prev != null && prev + m >= currentStart) {
            counter[prev] = counter[prev]!! - 1
            if (counter[prev]!! == 0.toLong()) {
                treeSet.remove(prev)
            }
            count += 1
        }
        counter.putIfAbsent(sortedTimes[i].second, 0)
        counter[sortedTimes[i].second] = counter[sortedTimes[i].second]!! + 1
        treeSet.add(sortedTimes[i].second)
    }
    return count
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val (n, m) = readLongs()
    val times = mutableListOf<Pair<Long, Long>>()
    for (i in 0 until n) {
        val (start, extra) = readLongs()
        val end = start + extra
        times.add(Pair(start, end))
    }
    val ans = greedy(times, m)
    println(ans)
}
```

This passes the examples, but fails on some hidden test cases.

I'd love some pointers on how I can improve the algorithm.

Comment: A greedy algorithm simply won't work. Ignore the idle time for simplicity. Suppose workstation W is available starting at some time t.There are two researchers that arrive at time t. Alice needs 10 minutes and Bob needs 20 minutes. Which one gets assigned to W? It depends on when the next researcher arrives. If Carol arrives at t+10, give W to Alice. If David arrives at t+20, give W to Bob. What if both Carol and David arrive? We need to see who arrives after them. What if seven researchers arrive at t+10 and eleven at t+20, all needing different times?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. :) The first two cases are covered (as I'm using a treeset, which allows finding the end time closest to a given start time). I think every other subsequent case can be treated based on the logic for those two cases..

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. After 5+ hours of  banging my head, I think you're right :) Any ideas on how to solve this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

- Let wa, wb two workstations **free/available**
- Researcher arrives.
- Penelope should assign the workstation the closest to lock (she minimizes the possibility of a locking machine)

---

1. Count maximum k of workstations used in parallel (O(2nlog(2n)))
2. Sort researchers by arrival time O(nlog(n))
3. Assign each researcher to its workstation

A workstation is either: locked, free (and gonna be locked), used.

Take the workstation the closest to lock **which is free**

that is:

```
min_{w in workstation} w.lockAt 
such that w.lockAt >= arrival + m
```

If there is no such machines, then use a locked machine. Whichever. e.g the smallest lockAt (by convenience).

To store the machines, an ordered set, sorted by lookAt, would allow maintenance in o(klog(k))

O(max(2nlog(2n) , nklog(k))) where k is the number of workstations...

On my potato machine, O3cpp, I can go up to 10^9 iteration in about 2s, so (very grossly)
nklogk <= 10^9 gives about ~k = 10^3.

Hope that there aren't so many machines